# dropdown hiding behind div in table

Tags: html, css, z-index, dropdown

Kindly refer to the image below

The dropdown keeps on hiding behind the table header

I have checked the opacity,z-index and everything.Still nothing happens.

Code for dropdown (pseudo dropdown creeated with div:

```
.content_dropdown{
    max-height: 120px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0.75em rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border: 1px solid #009cff;
    border-top-left-radius: 1px;
    border-top-right-radius: 1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    max-height: 154px;
}
```

Code for table header:

```
.task_stages_list_view-HEAD{
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgb(230, 231, 235);
    border-style: solid;
    min-height:42px;
    width: 1695px;
    display: block;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

P.S: I dont want to remove position:sticky to make the dropdown come above the table header.Any other solutions?

Comment: IMAGE REFERENCE:https://ibb.co/vhsxvr9

Comment: Not completely sure if this would work because I don't have the actual DOM elements to confirm. But yes, `z-index` of `.content_dropdown` should be more than `.task_stages_list_view-HEAD` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

From your code both  `.content_dropdown` and `.task_stages_list_view-HEAD` are positioned elements, you need to use the `z-index` property in both selectors to give them a stacking context that suits what you really want in your case since you have

```
.task_stages_list_view-HEAD{
...
z-index: 99999;
...
}
```

You need to declare a `z-index` property in `.content_dropdown` that will be higher that what you have in `.task_stages_list_view-HEAD` 
Try

```
.content_dropdown{
...
z-index: 100000;
...
}
```

So that the element with the `.content_dropdown` will appear closer to the user since it has a higher `z-index` and ontop of `.task_stages_list_view-HEAD`
NB- Any element with value for `z-index` lower than 99999 will appear behind `.task_stages_list_view-HEAD` to the user

Comment: You really need to take a look at [help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), as your answer is very poorly formatted. It is almost impossible to make any sense out it.

Comment: I just read it and I have edited my previous answer thanks you have been most helpful I will only get better